# How does one stop the "Select A Wireless Network" prompt on iOS 10 Beta?

Tags: iphone, ios, beta-seed-program

The "Select A Wireless Network" prompt keeps popping up every 5 seconds. I DO NOT have the "ask to join wireless networks" marked on and I am already joined to a network but this will not stop. Anyone have any fixes for that? It is a major PITA. Thanks.

Comment: It's beta software, so it might just be a bug which you can report with the Feedback Assistant.

Comment: @patrix Thx for responding. It definitely is a bug...I am wondering if anyone has figured out who to fix it before the next beta update comes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Trying erasing and restoring from backup. I am on iOS 10 beta and it doesn't ask me continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure to report the issue using Feedback Assistant. Then, try toggling the setting in Settings, as it might fix the issue. If it doesn't, try restarting the iPhone. Then you could also try backing up the iPhone, erasing all data on it, then restoring the backup. But, if that still doesn't fix the issue, and it really bothers you, you can always downgrade to iOS 9.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your phone off and start back up after about 3-5 minutes.  This resolved the issue for me.

The issue started yesterday when I tried to turn off "Ask to Join Networks" (although not having the issue) and it started prompting about every 5 minutes.  I tried to turn it back on and the issue persisted until I restarted my phone.

Comment: iOS 9.3.5 ipad 2, restarting worked.